# Passing date to a function in postgres

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

I am using postgres, and trying to define a function which accepts date as an input parameter.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.path_optimization(input_date date)
RETURNS TABLE(area_id_ uuid, result_uuids text[])
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
r RECORD;
BEGIN
-- Iterate through the records in pma_ranked
FOR r IN SELECT areaid, max_uuid FROM pma_ranked LOOP
--RAISE NOTICE 'Processing areaid: %, max_uuid: %', r.areaid, r.max_uuid;

RETURN QUERY
EXECUTE
'
WITH RECURSIVE
tree AS (
SELECT
g."centerPoint"::GEOMETRY AS vtcs,
NULL::GEOMETRY AS segment,
ARRAY[g.uuid] AS uuids
FROM
potential_missed_areas AS g
WHERE
g."areaID" = $1
AND g.uuid = $2
AND g.status = ''approved''
AND g."createdAt" = input_date
UNION ALL
SELECT
ST_Union(t.vtcs, v."centerPoint"),
ST_ShortestLine(t.vtcs, v."centerPoint"),
t.uuids || v.uuid
FROM
tree AS t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
SELECT
g.uuid,
g."centerPoint"
FROM
potential_missed_areas AS g
WHERE
g."areaID" = $1
AND g.status = ''approved''
AND g."createdAt" = input_date
AND NOT g.uuid = ANY(t.uuids)
ORDER BY
t.vtcs <-> g."centerPoint"
LIMIT
1
) AS v
),
NumberedRows AS (
SELECT
$1,uuids,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS RowNum
FROM tree
WHERE segment IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
$1,uuids
FROM NumberedRows
WHERE RowNum = (SELECT MAX(RowNum) FROM NumberedRows);
'
USING r.areaid, r.max_uuid;

END LOOP;
END;
$function$
;
```

When I call my function using:

```
select * from public.path_optimization('2023-10-04'::date)
```

I get the following error:

```
SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "input_date" does not exist
Where: PL/pgSQL function path_optimization(date) line 9 at RETURN QUERY
```

I have tried using $3 instead of input_date in my query, and then including input_date as the third item in the USING clause above, but that still did not work. Is there any thing I need to fix in the function definition?

Comment: `I have tried using $3 instead of input_date in my query, and then including input_date as the third item in the USING clause above, but that still did not work.` -- what was the error?

Comment: an empty result set, no error

Comment: perhaps I need to declare input_date? @fukanchik

Comment: try to play with your function. So if you negate  comparison to be like this: `AND g."createdAt" <> $3` does it return anything?

Comment: Why are you using `EXECUTE` at all?

Comment: @Bergi if i comment it out, the code gives an error

Comment: Comment out what? Gives what error? Please [edit] your question to include your attempt.

Comment: @Bergi you asked Why are you using EXECUTE at all? – So I commented "EXECUTE", and it gives an error which begins with SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "'
        WITH RECURSIVE
        tree AS (

Comment: Well you should not just remove the `EXECUTE` keyword, you should run the query that you currently have embedded in that string literal directly as a pl/pgsql statement.

Comment: @Bergi I thought that was what I was doing, isn't this how to run a pl/pgsql statement? I think what is missing is declaring input_date

Comment: No. `EXECUTE` is only for *dynamic* sql statements (constructed as strings), nothing else. If you just want to run a regular sql statement, [simply write in the pl/pgsql script](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-GENERAL-SQL). Or in your case, [in `RETURN QUERY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-RETURN-NEXT). The recursive CTE is also just a *`query`*.

Comment: "*I think what is missing is declaring input_date*" - yes. You could pass it as a `USING` parameter exactly like you already did for `r.areaid` and `r.max_uuid`, but really you just shouldn't use `EXECUTE`.

Comment: @Bergi even when i pass it as a USING parameter, it is giving a null result set.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters in a string literal (constant) are not replaced.

Use [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) to construct the query by interpolating the parameter explicitly:

```
RETURN QUERY
EXECUTE format(
           'WITH [...] AND g."createdAt" = %1$L [...] AND g."createdAt" = %1$L [...]',
           input_date
        )
        USING r.areaid, r.max_uuid;
```

Comment: could you please clarify what "AND g."createdAt" = %1s [...]" means

Comment: like should i use g."createdAt" = input_date?

Comment: No, it should be `%1s`. Isn't that clearly described in the documentation I linked to?

Comment: ok thanks, now it says SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: too few arguments for format()
  Where: PL/pgSQL function path_optimization(date) line 10 at RETURN QUERY

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the dollar. It should work now.

Comment: Now it says: SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: date = integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Where: PL/pgSQL function path_optimization(date) line 10 at RETURN QUERY

Comment: please note, I am using AND g."createdAt"::date = %1$s

Comment: I have added the updated code in an edit , thanks

Comment: Ah, so sorry, it was my error after all. I used `%1$s` instead of `%1$L`. Fixed.